# Complex number matrix calculation

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

How do I find a complex number $\lambda $ such that $\pmatrix{ 3&-2\\2&3}\vec v$ = $\lambda\vec v $ where $ \vec v $ is non-zero. Yes, this is a homework problem, I didn't learn complex number in my previous linear alg course.

add....

So far I found $\lambda = 3-2i$ is this the only solution?

Comment: What about  the **conjugate** of your $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand this notation (I edited and don't know if I edited correctly =p).

To find $\lambda$, calculate the characteristic polynomial (here, $I$ denote the identity matrix, and $A=\pmatrix{3&-2\\2&3}$)
$$
p(x)=\det(A-xI)=\det\pmatrix{3-x&-2\\2&3-x}=x^2-6x+13
$$
and the roots will be exactly the $\lambda$'s you want. In this case, $\lambda=3\pm 2i$.

(See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Characteristic_polynomial) for more details, the idea of "why this works", and how to calculate $\vec v$ such that $A\vec v=\lambda\vec v$)

Comment: Followed your procedure and it's definitely correct. I thought of solving it using eiganvectors but I don't know to solve polynomial for complex numbers.

Comment: @xiamx: if the polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, you can solve by the classical formula (independent if this is complex or no) $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ if the degree is greater, it can be hard solving... =p